# Terminology for $\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$

Tags: number-theory, functions, terminology

I have a model which contains a function $\phi:{\mathbb R}_+ \rightarrow {\mathbb R}_+$ that satifies:

$$\tag{*}\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$$

for all $x,y\in{\mathbb R}_+$. In Number Theory there is a property termed *completely multiplicative* ([see](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function)), but this is only defined for functions of integers. Although there is a certain overlap of property $(*)$ with this definition, property $(*)$ applies to the whole space ${\mathbb R}_+$. Can I say that $\phi(\cdot)$ is completely multiplicative or is there a more appropriate notation for this sort of functions?

**Update:**

Another related property is [additivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_function). $\phi(\cdot)$ can be seen as a log-additive function. This is, $\log\phi(xy)= \log\phi(x)+\log\phi(y)$.

Comment: I think you can safely call it completely multiplicative as it is so when you apply on the natural numbers, say.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you for your reply. The thing is that this property applies to the whole space ${\mathbb R}_+$, then I would like to find a definition for this kind of functions.

Comment: BTW, you probably mean *terminology* instead of *notation*.

Comment: @lhf Good point. I was not aware of that tag. Let me change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call it *multiplicative*, without further ado, unless this function is related to number theory.

You might also call it an endomorphism of the multiplicative group of positive real numbers, but it's probably overkill.

Comment: I am going to accept the answer since its provides a general terminology. In my context, I think log-additivity is enough. Cheers.